# Time Complexity of two loops

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

I have two loops written in C whereby the first runs `n` times, where `n` is the length of an input string. Assume the input string is: `*& 201 +ACD 3491 AASD 3`.

The loop will scan each character, and if a digit is encountered, it will calculate the length of the digit, and increment a pointer by that distance. So when the pointer `p` points to `2` and reads an integer, it will `sscanf` the number (`201`) and increment `p` by 3. Two nested loops where one runs `N` times and the other runs `M` times have a time complexity of `O(N * M)`.

Would it be safe to say that the time complexity in my algorithm is also `O(N * M)`, where `M` is the number of digits scanned at that particular iteration? If not, what would be the time complexity for the whole thing?

**EDIT:**

Here is some code

```
char c;
while ((c = fgets(fp)) != EOF) {
    // scans characters, if a digit is encountered, get digit_length
    for (int i = 0; i < digit_length; i++)
        p++;
}
```

Comment: don't want to answer because I could have misunderstood your explanation. pseudocode would be a lot better...

Comment: I don't see any "M" looping happening - it's just a constant operation if a digit is encountered, correct?

Comment: @RobI, Those were my thoughts exactly. sscanf should be a constant time operation, therefore the algorithm would still be O(1) multipled by an O(N) loop, making it O(N) run time.

Comment: Incrementing the pointer however is done in a for-loop. It looks as follows: `for (int i = 0; i < digit_length; i++) p++;`

Comment: Since [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) focuses on the growth of an algorithm when different sized inputs are provided, I claim that the "M" loop is overwhelmed by the "N" loop - you're talking about a decimal representation of a pointer, something that's most likely less than 20 characters, for the inner loop, while the string passed to it could be much longer.  Now, you're also looping within the file itself, which presents its own potential for complexity impacts.  I'd be interested to know what the expected sizes of the strings/files are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're scanf'ing all the following numbers:

```
201
01
1
3491
491
91
1
3
```

Then the time would be (worst case) O(N^2).  If you are avoiding this somehow (and you should be), then it will be O(N).

Comment: Why is that? `scanf` is constant time. Please check my edit above, I added some code and demonstrate what I mean by the nested loops.

Comment: `scanf` is not constant time.  Its running time is proportional to the length of the string it ends up scanning.

Comment: So if sscanf ends up scanning `M` digits, then the complexity is O(N*M). What about the loop I have above? Please check my added code.

Comment: I can't be sure because you don't show how you get `digit_length`, but assuming that's linear time your code looks good (O(N)).

Comment: `int digit_length = log10(x) + 1` So the inner for-loop that increments a few times every other outer loop iteration does not account into the complexity?